# Validating the cookie cypress throws 'TypeError: cy.chain is not a function

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am validating the cookie in my below 'login' Cypress test, but cypress throws following error :

> TypeError: cy.chain is not a function

Clearly imported the following under `'../support/index.js'` Can someone please advise why the error is throwing

```
import './commands'
```

cypress test:

```
describe("Login test validate cookie", () => {
    it.only('Verify the cookies test for login', function() {
        cy
        .login(Cypress.env('email'), Cypress.env('password'))
        cy
        .getCookie('csrftoken')
        .then((csrftoken) => {
            console.log(csrftoken)
        })
    })
```

Following is my 'login' method/function ../support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
    return cy.chain().request({
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        url: '${cypress.env("test_server")}',
        body: '{"email", "password"}',
    })
});
```

The below details are provided in 'cypress.env.json' file

```
{ 
  "email": "test@soccer.nl",
  "password": "test1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is correct; `cy.chain()` is indeed not a function. However, there are a number of issues in your command:

1. Unless you plan to chain off this command, you don't need to return anything. It certainly doesn't hurt anything though.
2. As mentioned previously, `.chain()` is unnecessary.
3. Your `url` field needs to use backticks (``) for the `${...}` to work.
4. Your `body` field is going to contain "email" and "password", instead of your actual email and password.

It's possible there are other issues, but these are the ones I can see.

Here's what your command would look like without those issues:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (email, password) => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        form: true,
        url: `${cypress.env("test_server")}`,
        body: `{"${email}", "${password}"}`,
    });
});
```

Comment: I have corrected the commands.js file, but still I am getting ReferenceError: cypress is not defined in console..cypress_runner.js:141349 ReferenceError: cypress is not defined
    at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:59156/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\index.js-384:45:20)
From previous event:
    at runCommand (http://localhost:59156/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:63790:14)
    at next (http://localhost:59156/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:63872:14)
From previous event:
    at http://localhost:59156/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:63891:37

Comment: If you're still getting errors, please post a new question with the full context.

Comment: I think he probably does want to chain off this command (it's a login command), but I'm quite sure returning cy.request should be enough? @soccerway try prepending a return statement before the `cy.request`